# Getting class variable value using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

In my business logic I have created classes for database operations like insert, update etc.
For this purpose I have created a class CDatabase which sets has some methods define in it like openconnection and closeconnection transation etc.

Now my logic class inherit that class

```
CAnswerLogic : CDatabase
{
   OpenConnection();
   BeginTrans();
   Command.CommandText = "PKG_ANSWER.PROC_ADD_ANSWERS";
}
```

Can I get the value of Command.CommandText using reflection. Command is a property inside CDatabse class.

I have written a method to return all the method of a class

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllMethod(string pstrClassName)
{
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

    var llistMethod = new List<string>();
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Server.MapPath(@"bin/InfoDomeBLL.dll"));
    try
    {
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsClass && type.Name == pstrClassName)
            {
                var method = type.GetMethods(flags);
                foreach (var methodInfo in method)
                {
                    llistMethod.Add(methodInfo.Name);

                    //var mb = methodInfo.GetMethodBody();
                    //foreach (LocalVariableInfo lvi in mb.LocalVariables)
                    //{
                    //    Response.Write("Local variable: " + lvi);
                    //}
                }
                var basetype= type.BaseType;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    return llistMethod;
}
```

In the web project i have added the reference of the bll project.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674947/get-property-value-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you use `type.GetProperties(flags);` instead of `type.GetMethods(flags);` you will find the property you are looking for. Then, do `propertyInfo.GetValue( Command, null );` to get the value.

Comment: will i be able to find the value of the property of the parent class. Because Command is the property of the base class CDatabase.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you do *not* specify `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` it will give you all properties of all classes up the hierarchy. Just lookup these methods on MSDN.

Comment: I am not able to solve my problem. In my class I have different methods. I want to know the value of the property Command.CommandText which is inside a particular method and command is declared in my parent class. Hope I am able to tell you my problem.